# ScaleGestureDetector on custom View inside HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, view, touch-event, horizontalscrollview, pinch

I'm quite new to Android programming, and I have trouble getting the intended behaviour on a layout that's built up like this: The main layout is a simple `LinearLayout`, in turn containing a `HorizontalScrollView` which in turn contains a custom view, which is largish (about 2000 pixels wide when not zoomed).

That works fine, my custom view displays inside the `HorizontalScrollView`, and it's scrollable, flickable and everything. So far, so good.

The next thing I wanted to do was zooming the custom view. In order to achieve that, I overrode the `onTouchEvent()` of the custom view

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent)
{
    if (_gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

and receive events in my `SimpleOnScaleGestureListener`. I pass those into the view for computing the new zooming factor, and even that works.

Now comes my little problem: Pinching/zooming only works if I pinch "vertically". The intuitive "horizontal" pinch seems to be consumed by the `HorizontalScrollView`, which does some scrolling instead.

What's happening here, and how can I get the behaviour I want, i.e. being able to

- flick and scroll using the `HorizontalScrollView`, and
- being able to zoom by pinching the custom view?

Comment: Hey, have you got any solution to this problem because I am facing a similar problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I have for the time being abandonded that project. Sorry.

Comment: Hey, have you got the solution for this? I got the same problem too :(

Comment: No, I still haven't. I'm not working on this currently.